# Optional attributes in tag helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I have a tag helper along the lines of the following:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("foo", Attributes = "bar")]
public class FooTagHelper : TagHelper

[HtmlAttributeName("bar")]
public bool Bar { get; set; }
```

When I add the following to a view, the tag helper processes the target as expected:

```
<foo bar="true"></foo>
```

However, what I would like to do is make `bar` optional e.g. `<foo></foo>` If it has been left off, I would like it to default to `false`

Is this possible? This source code comment for the `HtmlTargetElementAttribute.Attributes` property seems to indicate not:

> // Summary:
>   A comma-separated System.String of attribute names the HTML element must contain
>   for the Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.TagHelpers.ITagHelper to run. * at the end of
>   an attribute name acts as a prefix match.

Answer (score 7):

You could remove "bar" from being a required attribute.

You can do that by overriding the Process method and checking whether the attribute exists.  If it does not, add the Bar attribute using its name and value.  You could explicitly set the value to `false` but the property Bar is false by default anyway.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("foo")]
public class FooTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("bar")]
    public bool Bar { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (!output.Attributes.ContainsName(nameof(Bar)))
        {
            output.Attributes.Add(nameof(Bar), Bar);
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers!

If you have not yet done so, I would suggest taking a look at the documentation available here https://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/tag-helpers/index.html.

Comment: The tag helper will not process the recaptcha element full stop... `Process()` is never called.

Comment: This should be working fine and has turned Bar into an optional attribute. It will render `<foo></foo>` as `<foo bar="False"></foo>`. Perhaps there is another issue within the tag helper you are really using?

Comment: When I tried this, the breakpoint would only hit if the attribute was also included when using the tag helper. e.g. using your example it would only work if I used it like: <foo bar="">. Is it possible to not have to include the attribute at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to check if the optional attribute is explicitly specified in the Html, you can check `context.AllAttributes`, you won't find it in `output.Attributes` as specified in the previous post.

I noticed that my TagHelper wasn't rendered if I left away the (optional) attribute `OnlyUrlOfMenuItem` in the Html. I just had to remove the attribute `OnlyUrlOfMenuItem` from the list of required attributes `HtmlTargetElement()` as stated by [Mat Hellums](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234202/mat-hellums) above. Since I don't want this attribute to appear in the final output, I didn't need to add the attribute with `output.Attributes.Add()` as stated in the previous post.

Here is my code with the optional attribute `OnlyUrlOfMenuItem` that has a default value of `false`:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = "MenuItem, LangCode")]
public class ATagHelper : TagHelper
{
    readonly IFhpMenuProvider _fhpMenuProvider;

    public ATagHelper(IFhpMenuProvider fhpMenuProvider)
    {
        _fhpMenuProvider = fhpMenuProvider;
        OnlyUrlOfMenuItem = false;
    }

    [HtmlAttributeName("LangCode")]
    public string LangCode { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("MenuItem")]
    public string MenuItemKey { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("OnlyUrlOfMenuItem")]
    public bool OnlyUrlOfMenuItem { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = _fhpMenuProvider.GetMenuItem(MenuItemKey, LangCode);
        if (menuItem != null)
        {
            ...
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuItem.Tooltip) == false && OnlyUrlOfMenuItem == false)
            {
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("title", menuItem.Tooltip);
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuItem.Caption) == false && OnlyUrlOfMenuItem == false)
            {
                output.Content.SetContent(menuItem.Caption);
            }
        }
        base.Process(context, output);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get attributes to be optional is if I ***did not*** include them in the `Attributes` section of `HtmlTargetElement`.

so this `[HtmlTargetElement("foo", Attributes = "bar")]` changes to `[HtmlTargetElement("foo")]`

then also remove the `[HtmlAttributeName("bar")]` here:

```
[HtmlAttributeName("bar")]
public bool Bar { get; set; }
```

so completed changes look like:

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("foo")]
public class FooTagHelper : TagHelper
{
   public bool Bar { get; set; }
   public string FooBar { get; set; }
}
```

***also make sure any properties you reference in your tag are kebab-case, example:***

```
<foo bar="true" foo-bar="make sure to use kebab-case!"></foo>
```